# Day and Month calculation does not return expected output in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-7

I want to calculate the time difference between tow days..

This is my code:

```
private static string CalculateDayMonth(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    int totalMonth = 0;
    string returnValue = "";

    if (date1 >= date2)
    {
        int days = date1.Day - date2.Day;
        int months = date1.Month - date2.Month;
        int years = date1.Year - date2.Year;

        if (months < 0)
        {
            months += 12;
            years -= 1;
        }

        if (days < 0)
        {
            int dayToSubtract = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date2.Year, date2.Month);
            days = days + dayToSubtract;
            months -= 1;
        }

        if (years > 0)
            totalMonth = years * 12;
        else
            years = 0;

        totalMonth += months;

        if (totalMonth <= 0)
            returnValue = string.Format(AppResources.Label50414, days.ToString());
        else
            returnValue = string.Format(AppResources.Label50415, totalMonth.ToString());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

My Input dates are : 
**Jan 2, 2015 14:02:47 PM - 
Dec 15, 2014 16:14:50 PM**

Expected output is **17 days**

But Actual output is : **18 days**.

I try some other examples also. But that also giving same output.

Please let me know where i did mistake.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd suggest using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project to handle this and other date/time issues. No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Why would the answer be 17 days though? December 15th + 17 days is January 1st, not January 2nd. (December has 31 days...)

Comment: i think its calculating correct.calculate days in december(31-15)= 16 + 2 days of january = 18.

Comment: I check with [this link](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=12&y1=2014&d2=2&m2=1&y2=2015&h1=16&i1=14&s1=50&h2=14&i2=02&s2=47). It shows **17 days, 21 hours, 47 minutes and 57 seconds**

Comment: @Vijay Because that link calculates hour parts as well. You didn't _even_ use/calculate the hours parts of your `DateTime`'s in your code.

Comment: @Vijay you are using just day, month and year in ur code, may be this is the problem.

Comment: Yes.. I need like that calculations only. My client requirement time is 17 only. They only show that link and show the calculation to me.

Comment: Use debug and see it ...

Comment: isn't there a defined method ? do you have to write it by yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't *even* calculate of your hours, minutes and seconds part. Without hour parts, [there are `18` days between January 2 and December 15](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=12&y1=2014&d2=2&m2=1&y2=2015&h1=&i1=&s1=&h2=&i2=&s2=) based their midnights.

But your [link](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=12&y1=2014&d2=2&m2=1&y2=2015&h1=16&i1=14&s1=50&h2=14&i2=02&s2=47) *does* calculate hour, minute and second parts as well. Since December 15 has higher hour part than January 2, the difference between these dates will be less than `18` days. That's why they are different.

Looks like you just need to use simple [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) like;

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2015, 1, 2, 14, 2, 47);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 12, 15, 16, 14, 50);

var ts = dt1 - dt2;
Console.WriteLine(ts.Days); // 17
Console.WriteLine(ts.Hours); // 21
Console.WriteLine(ts.Minutes); // 47
Console.WriteLine(ts.Seconds); // 57
```

As formatted;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes and {3} seconds",
                  ts.Days,
                  ts.Hours,
                  ts.Minutes,
                  ts.Seconds); // 17 days, 21 hours, 47 minutes and 57 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private struct DateResult
    {
        public int years;
        public int months;
        public int days;
    }
    private DateResult Date_Difference(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        DateResult d_r;
        d_r.years = 0;
        d_r.months = 0;
        d_r.days = 0;
        DateTime frm_date, to_Date;
        int key=0;
        if (d1 > d2)
        {
            frm_date = d2;
            to_Date = d1;
        }
        else
        {
            frm_date = d1;
            to_Date = d2;
        }

        if (frm_date.Day > to_Date.Day) //10  5  //7  24
        {
            key = month_day[frm_date.Month - 1];

            if (key == -1)
            {
                if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(frm_date.Year))
                    key = 29;
                else
                    key = 28;

            }                
        }
        if (key == 0)
        {
            d_r.days = to_Date.Day - frm_date.Day;
        }
        else
        {
            d_r.days = (to_Date.Day + key) - frm_date.Day;
            key = 1;
        }

        if ((frm_date.Month+key) > to_Date.Month)
        {
            d_r.months = (to_Date.Month + 12) - (frm_date.Month + key);
            key = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            d_r.months = to_Date.Month - (frm_date.Month+key);
            key=0;
        }
        d_r.years = to_Date.Year - (frm_date.Year+key);
        return d_r; 
    }
```

This code in C#.. It works for me... we can also know about Hours, Minutes and Seconds